# Is there any way to force some pages use Edge Chromium mode and others Edge IE11 mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

The project that I'm working on must be compatible with IE11 however some of the pages can work fine with Chrome but only if Edge can be somehow hinted to not load certain page in IE mode. I'm curious if there is any way to force Edge use Chrome mode on some pages using JS/HTML. Not with enterprise lists...

Tried googling it, also found some IE specific tags, the only thing i got from all of that is probably confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no JS/HTML way to force sites to load in IE/Edge mode. You can only use the [Enterprise Sites List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-site-list-manager#add-single-sites-to-your-site-list) to configure sites to load in IE mode and Edge mode.